# Panel background color does not match bitmap

Tags: bitmap, panel

Visual studio express 15 written in basic. I have set a panel background color.

```
        Panel_Pixel_Drop.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(160, 211, 211, 211)
```

I have placed a picturebox inside panel and reference the image inside resources folder to a image

```
            Pic_Link_Image(intLink_Number).Image = My.Resources.Link_Close
```

The image was created in the VS15 paint program.  I used the custom color setup in the paint program to produce the same background color as the panel but the image is darker than the panel background color. The only setting I cannot find to setup is the lum which is 170 on created image. Is it possible to get same colors to display ?

Comment: it's because you have transparency.  If the image is transparent then any colors basically add on to the colors that are partially visible in the image with whatever is in the background.  Try solid colors(255 alpha) so that you can get a perfect match

Comment: I tried that ARGB(255,211,211,211) for panel color but its still off.  I assume Its the colors in the paint program that creates the mismatch. Paint program color RGB 211,211,211 so I tried using photoshop to create image but get same results. Any thoughts?